# qt3dwindow.h missing in focal and xenial

Tags: apt, package-management, compiling, qt, qt5

The way dev package for Qt are designed in ubuntu is extremly disturbing to me.

Lets take a simple example, QForwardRenderer include file for instance:
It is part of bionic: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/qt3d5-dev/filelist
It is part of xenial: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/qt3d5-dev/filelist
It is NOT part of focal: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/qt3d5-dev/filelist

Now lets now try to get another example, I checked examples from official 5.12.8 release of QT: https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/5.12.8/examples/qt3d/simple-cpp/main.cpp
And they do feature qt3dwindow.h
https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/5.12.8/src/extras/defaults/qt3dwindow.h

So I am 100% sure that qt3dwindow.h should be part of any proper release of a dev package for qt3d at version 5.12.8 (the one packaged in focal)

However there is no such file in focal release, I have absolutely no explanation for such a behaviour:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=qt3dwindow.h

It is part of bionic: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/qt3d5-dev/filelist
It is NOT part of xenial: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/qt3d5-dev/filelist
It is NOT part of focal: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/qt3d5-dev/filelist

The presence/absence of include file for QT dev packages seems completely random to me, what is happening here ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Qt5 came out in December-2012, so Qt4 days where numbered from that point on; though as is normal it was still the default for some time (and Qt4's life extended as announced) as Qt5 matured. Qt4 reached it's final EOL in 2015, but wasn't removed from Debian/Ubuntu until 2019.  As you note with the dates (Qt4 EOL 2015 but not removed till 2019) shows the EOL date upstream doesn't impact Debian/Ubuntu until releases which contained it EOL, so watching upstream provides the clues if you look. As a developer using a Qt toolkit, don't you watch the life cycle of the Qt toolkit you rely on?

Comment: I am not using Qt on a regular basis this is why some aspects are a mistery to me. Especially the qt3d stuff. The only thing I understand here, is that include files from git release 5.12.8 are != include file from ubuntu dev package for 5.12.8 and I cannot compile an example from 5.12.8 release with ubuntu . (Eventually I did managed but I had to manually import include files.

Comment: You would be best to remove the packaged version of Qt/Qt Creator and install it using the installer you can download from their website. This will also provide you with a maintenance tool which allows you to control what versions of Qt you have.